# Hundreds of Service Fabric Certificate Error

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-service-fabric

Service Fabric 2.8 on Azure. I am getting hundreds of these warnings in the Fabric Admin Event Log.

I have both Cluster Certificate and another SSL Certificate for the public websites.

```
partial chain? certChain->rgpChain[0]->cElement = 1, certChain->rgpChain[0]->rgpElement[0]->TrustStatus.dwInfoStatus = 2
```

Do you have a clue what is this and how can I sort it out?

Comment: You forgot to post some of the warnings in your question.

Answer (score 0):

We solved this issue by looking to another nodes, where has been found errors in event log like Thumbprint::Initialize: Failed to parse ....... as certificate thumbprint, the format should be ........ So check the ClusterManifest.xml, and Settings.xml with correct thumbprint, if you don't have one hidden symbol before thumbprint, and use this link to solve the errors: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/troubleshooting-expired-certificate-azure-service-fabric/ba-p/2031756

Comment: Thank you, this is so long ago that I forgot that I even posted this question or its context but thank you anyway